# How can I add two gradient layer styles photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, gradient, layer-style

I made a rectangular shape. I set it's layer style to gradient overlay and the layer mode to multiply.

It looks great with one layer, the one on the left. However when I make another shape and repeat the process only with different gradient orientation.. it does not seem to properly multiply over the previous. Hence the interruption in the corner.I also tried grouping the shape and adding the second layer style to the group.

Practically I need a left to right gradient and a bottom to top one blending together to form a nice corner shadow.

This is a screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the blend mode of the gradient style itself too, not only the layer blending mode.[image]